# Masive error after updating to Firebase Crashlytics SDK

Tags: android, firebase, crash-reports, migrate, crashlytics-android

I recently upgraded my app to Firebase Crashlytics SDK following this guide (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android) . I tested it and it worked properly so I uploaded it to Google Play.

The problem is that I am receiving many error reports from my users since then. The report is as follows:

```
 java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: 
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2086)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute (Executors.java:630)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.onComplete (zzc.java:6)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zza (zzr.java:19)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.setResult (zzu.java:86)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzo.onSuccess (zzo.java:9)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run (zzn.java:4)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzt.execute (zzt.java:2)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.onComplete (zzm.java:11)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zza (zzr.java:19)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.zze (zzu.java:132)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.addOnSuccessListener (zzu.java:32)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzp.run (zzp.java:18)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun (ExecutorUtils.java:60)
  at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run (BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)
```

I have only made the changes that appear in the guide so I do not understand why I am receiving that error if I have not modified anything other than the syntax to that of the new SDK.

The error report does not refer to any point of my app so I do not know what may be happening.
I have searched the Internet and can not find information about it. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: this issue is being discussed on the firebase-android-sdk Github repository.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2013